# Rails update foreign key with id of association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an association with an id, but the foreign key is not being set.

Some setup:

```
Foo has_many :bars
Bar belongs_to :foo

foo = Foo.new.save
bar = Bar.new(foo: foo)
```

The output:

```
bar.foo = foo
bar.foo.id = 1
bar.foo_id = nil # Why is this nil!?
```

Other than assigning `bar.foo_id = 1`, is there a method to update the associated foreign key, so `bar.foo_id == 1` **without saving**?

There must be some kind of `#update_foreign_keys`, or `#update_associations` method, right?

I'm running Rails 4.2 with Ruby 2.1.2

Comment: Why don't you just save `bar` once you've set its `foo` attribute to `foo`? So, something like this: `bar.foo = foo; bar.save; puts bar.foo_id`.

Comment: try `foo = Foo.build` `bar = foo.bars.create(foo: foo)`

Comment: thanks for the input, I am needing to do it without saving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id is set by the database, not by rails, that's why is empty.

You need to save each object in order to get an id.

You can save the object in a transaction in order to get one in case you need it to perform any magic.

And about the code:

```
bar.foo = foo
bar.foo.id = 1            <- This retrieves the ruby#object_id
bar.foo_id = nil          <- This retrieves the database#id
```

That's why the second one is nil.